# How to merge three different csv files into one Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am relativly new to Python and I have a question:
How can I merge the data from three different csv files?

csv1:
label

csv2:
timestamp

csv3:
start

I tried this:

```py
    concate_data = pd.concat([label,timestamp,start])
```

It kinda works but the outcome is wrong. I got something like this:

| label | timestamp | start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eating | null | null |
| Eating | null | null |
| null | 2012:02:02 12:00:01 | null |
| null | null | 1 |
| null | null | 0 |

How can I concat these three different csv files into one so that they look like the following?

| label | timestamp | start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eating | 2012:02:02 12:00:01 | 1 |
| Eating | 2012:02:02 12:01:01 | 0 |
| Eating | 2012:02:02 12:01:01 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***All you need to do is add axis=1 to pd.concat***

So, basically:

```
concate_data = pd.concat([label,timestamp,start], axis=1)
```

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list elements
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
print(df)

concate_data = pd.concat([df,df,df], axis=1)
print(concate_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you don't want to concat vertically but horizontally. Right?

Try this:

`concate_data = pd.concat([label,timestamp,start], axis=1)`